# Проблема с кнопкой "Показать еще" на Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Делаю кнопку "показать еще" в шаблоне.
Все подключил, кнопка вроде срабатывает, но анонсы не раскрываются. Видимо где-то допустил ошибку, не могли бы мне помочь?

Подключил в *functions.php* js скрипт:

```
function true_loadmore_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // скорее всего он уже будет подключен, это на всякий случай
  wp_enqueue_script('true_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().
    '/loadmore.js', array('jquery'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_loadmore_scripts');

function true_load_posts() {

  $args = unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['query']));
  $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
  $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
  query_posts($args);
  if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()): the_post();
  get_template_part('template-parts/post/content', get_post_format());
  endwhile;
  endif;
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
```

Далее добавил в шаблон вот такой код:

```
<div class="row">

  <?php
    $args = array('cat' => '7','numberposts' => 2 ,'order' => 'DESC' );
    query_posts($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  ?>
    <div class="col single-featured-image">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail('full'); endif; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <script>
      var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
      var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
      var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
      var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
    </script>
    <div id="true_loadmore">Загрузить ещё</div>
  <?php endif; ?>   

</div>
```

Вот сам скрипт *loadmor.js*

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#true_loadmore').click(function() {
    $(this).text('Загружаю...');
    var data = {
      'action': 'loadmore',
      'query': true_posts,
      'page': current_page
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl, // обработчик
      data: data, // данные
      type: 'POST', // тип запроса
      success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
          $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
          current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
          if (current_page == max_pages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
        } else {
          $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Нажимаю на кнопку, кнопка пропадает, а анонсы не раскрываются. Что не так?

Comment: локализуйте с начала проблему, а иначе не понятно как вам помочь

Comment: Вообщем нажимаю на кнопку "Показать еще" кнопка начинает писать "Загружаю" и начинает анимация загрузки, после это сразу изщезает, а мне нужно после того, как она изщезла - раскрылся еще 3 поста из этой рубрики и т.д